# Why favicon is not render on Ror 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I use this in my application.html.erb

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="<%= "#{Rails.root}/public/favicon.ico" %>">
```

I use it in my development.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

I use this on my application.rb

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Static, File.join(Rails.root, 'public')
```

I have my favicon.ico in public folder but this tag do no more

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/Users/ivansizyh/Desktop/TechInterrogate/public/favicon.ico">
```

I do all that i write

Answer (score 1):

The base folder for your rails app is your `public` folder, so your link for your favicon should look like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
```

there's also a helper in rails:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

which might be worth trying, but you'll need to move your `favicon.ico` file to the `app/assets/images` folder.

I also think you can leave out either of these and as long and you name your file `favicon.ico` and put it in the public folder, it should just work.  See here for docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-favicon_link_tag.

Also make sure your favicon.ico file is in the correct format and readable.

Comment: ye i dont now what is happening but it work with another path